# Need help on passing PHP variable to jQuery using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a variable in the PHP code called `$final_value`. I am trying to pass it into a jQuery file using `$.ajax` but I am unable to do so. Any help will be appreciated.

HTML (test.php)

```
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p class="result">
    <?php            
        $final_value = 27.00;            
        echo '<strong>'.$final_value.'</strong>';
        echo json_encode($final_value);
    ?>
    </p>
    <p id="test"></p>        
</body>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    createValue();

    function createValue(){        
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/test.php',
        method: 'post',            
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output){
            $('#test').append(output);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: Um, your test.php file includes non json data.... so the response from that file would be an html document, thus unparsable.  Try taking off the dataType: 'json' and console.log(output) to see what you get.  Then you can start the process of manipulating the output to match what you want.

Comment: @Taplar I think that I am going to change it into `dataType; 'html'` and see how things work out because my PHP code is part of an HTML file. Still working out how to get the `$final_value` from HTML though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP script returns HTML, not JSON. So use `dataType: 'html'` in the AJAX call. But you shouldn't have `<body>` around the HTML -- it's going to get inserted into a DIV that's already in the body, and you can't have multiple `<body>` tags in the same document.

You can get rid of `echo json_encode($final_value);` in the PHP, it's not needed.

Or change the PHP so it *only* echoes the JSON -- get rid of all the HTML around it. Then your jQuery code will need to wrap the response into HTML and add it to the DOM:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/test.php',
    method: 'post',            
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(output){
        $('#test').append("<strong>" + output + "</strong>");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: ahh I see. If I use `dataType: 'html'`, how would I get it to detect the `$final_value` part of php?

Comment: Put the response in a DIV, and then use `$("#div").find("strong").text()` to get the value.

Comment: There is no need for ajax in this case then. We can directly detect the value from the HTML file. Thanks.